# Linear transformation and pre-images

Tags: linear-algebra

I’m trying to search on internet in a way to solve this question but i can’t find anything, and my exam is so close. 
Given a Matrix like : **A**= $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & a^2 & a \\
    4 & 2 & a^2+3 \\ 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ -Determine for which value of **a** we have $ {f^-} $ *(1,2,0)* is not empty. 
When the inverse image is empty and when its not ? 
I reduce the matrix to echelon form so it is
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 2 & a^2+3 \\
    0 & 2a^2-2 & 2a^2-a^2-3 \\
    0 & 0 & -a^2-1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ Really need help, Thanks in advance❤️

Answer (score 2):

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & a^2 & a \\
    4 & 2 & a^2+3 \\ 
    \end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & a^2-1 & a-1 \\
    0 & 0 & a^2+1 \\ 
    \end{pmatrix}=2(a^4-1)$$

Thus, assuming the matrix is a real one, but for $\;a\neq\pm1\;$ the matrix is regular and thus $\;f^{-1}(v)\neq\emptyset\;$ for any $\;v\in\Bbb R^3\;$ . Now, for $\;a=\pm1\;$ we get that our matrix is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 1 \\
    2 & 1 & \pm1 \\
    4 & 2 & 4 \\ 
    \end{pmatrix}\implies f^{-1}(1,2,0)^t\neq\emptyset\iff\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}\in Span\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\4\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}1\\\pm1\\4\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}\iff$$

the last row in the following matrix vanishes after performing elementary row operations on it:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&2&4\\1&1&2\\1&\pm1&4\\1&2&0\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_1\leftrightarrow R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\2&2&4\\1&\pm1&4\\1&2&0\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-2R_1\\R_3-4R_1\\R_4-R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\0&0&0\\0&\begin{cases}\;0\\\!\!-2\end{cases}&2\\0&1&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

and we can see what happens no matter whether $\;a=1\;$ or $\;a=-1\;$...Now, can you justify the above?

Comment: When $a = -1$ the matrix obtained is different than the one you wrote. However, I think you already showed enough for the OP to finish the job.

Comment: True, I missed that $\;a\;$ there. I shall edit later...mayb,e but goodyou got the general idea.

Comment: So you mean when the vector ( 1,2,0 ) belong to the span ( Linearly dependent ) so the inverse image becomes not empty and when it vanishes it is empty ?

Comment: And as i see for both values of **a** the vector <1,2,0 > won’t vanish

Comment: @TarekChafei Yes, it won't...and thus the vector is not in the image of the map (the matrix) and $\;f^{-1}(1,2,0)\;$ is empty.

Answer (score 0):

*Sketch:* If your work so far is correct, then there are three cases: $a$ equal to *something*, $a$ equal to *something else*, or $a$ equal to neither. For the third case there is nothing to do because the matrix has full rank. The other two must be done by substituting the values.

Comment: Yeah but i my question is to determine the inverse image when its empty and when its not